# PyQt4 / QTableView : How to change the style of selection rectangle?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview

I am trying to change the style of selection rectangle in QTableView.

I have tried with stylesheet; but it allowed me to set only the selection background color as shown in **Figure 1**. I wanted the selection rectangle as shown in **Figure 2**. (No Fill Color + Thick  black border)

Any idea?

```
def TableUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
    Dialog.resize(343, 179)

    self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(Dialog)
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 321, 121))
    self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("selection-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
    "selection-background-color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
```

[image]

Full Code Sample: https://justpaste.it/5fe3r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To style the selected cell you can target `QTableView::item::selected` in your stylesheet.

```py
self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet('''
    QTableView::item::selected {
      border: 5px solid black;
    }
''')
```

[image: qtableview_item_selected]